# How to solve Einsteins riddle with z3py the elegant way?

Tags: python, z3py

z3py guys have provided a code what is based here https://github.com/0vercl0k/z3-playground/blob/master/einstein_riddle_z3.py . However comparing to this https://artificialcognition.github.io/who-owns-the-zebra the solution is rather complicated, long and ugly. I do not really want to switch the libraries as z3py seems more advanced and maintained. So I started to work on my version, but I fail to declare some parts (lack of knowledge or not possible?). Here is what I have and where I get stuck (2 comments):

```py
from z3 import *

color = Int('color')
nationality = Int('nationality')
beverage = Int('beverage')
cigar = Int('cigar')
pet = Int('pet')
house = Int('house')

color_variations = Or(color==1, color==2, color==3, color==4, color==5)
nationality_variations = Or(nationality==1, nationality==2, nationality==3, nationality==4, nationality==5)
beverage_variations = Or(beverage==1, beverage==2, beverage==3, beverage==4, beverage==5)
cigar_variations = Or(cigar==1, cigar==2, cigar==3, cigar==4, cigar==5)
pet_variations = Or(pet==1, pet==2, pet==3, pet==4, pet==5)
house_variations = Or(house==1, house==2, house==3, house==4, house==5)

s = Solver()

s.add(color_variations)
s.add(nationality_variations)
s.add(beverage_variations)
s.add(cigar_variations)
s.add(pet_variations)
s.add(house_variations)

# This is not right
#s.add(Distinct([color, nationality, beverage, cigar, pet]))

s.add(And(Implies(nationality==1, color==1), Implies(color==1, nationality==1))) #the Brit (nationality==1) lives in the red (color==1) house
s.add(And(Implies(nationality==2, pet==1), Implies(pet==1, nationality==2))) #the Swede (nationality==2) keeps dogs (pet==1) as pets
s.add(And(Implies(nationality==3, beverage==1), Implies(beverage==1, nationality==3))) #the Dane (nationality==3) drinks tea (beverage=1)
s.add(And(Implies(color==2, beverage==2), Implies(beverage==2, color==2))) #the green (color==2) house's owner drinks coffee (beverage==2)
s.add(And(Implies(cigar==1, pet==2), Implies(pet==2, cigar==1))) #the person who smokes Pall Mall (cigar==1) rears birds ([pet==2])
s.add(And(Implies(color==4, cigar==2), Implies(cigar==2, color==4))) #the owner of the yellow (color==4) house smokes Dunhill (cigar==2)
s.add(And(Implies(house==3, beverage==3), Implies(beverage==3, house==3))) #the man living in the center (hause==3) house drinks milk (beverage==3)
s.add(And(Implies(nationality==4, house==1), Implies(house==1, nationality==4))) #the Norwegian (nationality==4) lives in the first house (house==1)
s.add(And(Implies(cigar==3, beverage==4), Implies(beverage==4, cigar==3))) #the owner who smokes BlueMaster (cigar==3) drinks beer (beverage==4)
s.add(And(Implies(nationality==5, cigar==4), Implies(cigar==4, nationality==5))) #the German (nationality==5) smokes Prince (cigar==4)

# I can't figure our this part, so I can keep it short and efficient
# the green (color==2) house is on the left of the white (color==3) house
```

Currently looking into direction of `ForAll` and `Function`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an enumeration for the different kinds of things here. Also, you can't just get away with having one color variable: After all, each house has a different color, and you want to track it separately. A better idea is to make `color`, `nationality`, etc., all uninterpreted functions; mapping numbers to colors, countries, etc., respectively.

Here's the Haskell solution for this problem, using the SBV library which uses z3 via the SMTLib interface, following the strategy I described: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-8.8/docs/src/Documentation.SBV.Examples.Puzzles.Fish.html

Translating this strategy to Python, we have:

```py
from z3 import *

# Sorts of things we have
Color      , (Red     , Green   , White     , Yellow   , Blue)   = EnumSort('Color'      , ('Red'     , 'Green'   , 'White'     , 'Yellow'   , 'Blue'))
Nationality, (Briton  , Dane    , Swede     , Norwegian, German) = EnumSort('Nationality', ('Briton'  , 'Dane'    , 'Swede'     , 'Norwegian', 'German'))
Beverage   , (Tea     , Coffee  , Milk      , Beer     , Water)  = EnumSort('Beverage'   , ('Tea'     , 'Coffee'  , 'Milk'      , 'Beer'     , 'Water'))
Pet        , (Dog     , Horse   , Cat       , Bird     , Fish)   = EnumSort('Pet'        , ('Dog'     , 'Horse'   , 'Cat'       , 'Bird'     , 'Fish'))
Sport      , (Football, Baseball, Volleyball, Hockey   , Tennis) = EnumSort('Sport'      , ('Football', 'Baseball', 'Volleyball', 'Hockey'   , 'Tennis'))

# Uninterpreted functions to match "houses" to these sorts. We represent houses by regular symbolic integers.
c = Function('color',       IntSort(), Color)
n = Function('nationality', IntSort(), Nationality)
b = Function('beverage',    IntSort(), Beverage)
p = Function('pet',         IntSort(), Pet)
s = Function('sport',       IntSort(), Sport)

S = Solver()

# Create a new fresh variable. We don't care about its name
v = 0
def newVar():
    global v
    i = Int("v" + str(v))
    v = v + 1
    S.add(1 <= i, i <= 5)
    return i

# Assert a new fact. This is just a synonym for add, but keeps everything uniform
def fact0(f):
    S.add(f)

# Assert a fact about a new fresh variable
def fact1(f):
    i = newVar()
    S.add(f(i))

# Assert a fact about two fresh variables
def fact2(f):
    i = newVar()
    j = newVar()
    S.add(i != j)
    S.add(f(i, j))

# Assert two houses are next to each other
def neighbor(i, j):
    return (Or(i == j+1, j == i+1))

fact1 (lambda i   : And(n(i) == Briton,     c(i) == Red))                       # The Briton lives in the red house.
fact1 (lambda i   : And(n(i) == Swede,      p(i) == Dog))                       # The Swede keeps dogs as pets.
fact1 (lambda i   : And(n(i) == Dane,       b(i) == Tea))                       # The Dane drinks tea.
fact2 (lambda i, j: And(c(i) == Green,      c(j) == White, i == j-1))           # The green house is left to the white house.
fact1 (lambda i   : And(c(i) == Green,      b(i) == Coffee))                    # The owner of the green house drinks coffee.
fact1 (lambda i   : And(s(i) == Football,   p(i) == Bird))                      # The person who plays football rears birds.
fact1 (lambda i   : And(c(i) == Yellow,     s(i) == Baseball))                  # The owner of the yellow house plays baseball.
fact0 (                 b(3) == Milk)                                           # The man living in the center house drinks milk.
fact0 (                 n(1) == Norwegian)                                      # The Norwegian lives in the first house.
fact2 (lambda i, j: And(s(i) == Volleyball, p(j) == Cat,      neighbor(i, j)))  # The man who plays volleyball lives next to the one who keeps cats.
fact2 (lambda i, j: And(p(i) == Horse,      s(j) == Baseball, neighbor(i, j)))  # The man who keeps the horse lives next to the one who plays baseball.
fact1 (lambda i   : And(s(i) == Tennis,     b(i) == Beer))                      # The owner who plays tennis drinks beer.
fact1 (lambda i   : And(n(i) == German,     s(i) == Hockey))                    # The German plays hockey.
fact2 (lambda i, j: And(n(i) == Norwegian,  c(j) == Blue,     neighbor(i, j)))  # The Norwegian lives next to the blue house.
fact2 (lambda i, j: And(s(i) == Volleyball, b(j) == Water,    neighbor(i, j)))  # The man who plays volleyball has a neighbor who drinks water.

# Determine who owns the fish
fishOwner = Const("fishOwner", Nationality)
fact1 (lambda i: And(n(i) == fishOwner, p(i) == Fish))

r = S.check()
if r == sat:
    m = S.model()
    print(m[fishOwner])
else:
    print("Solver said: %s" % r)
```

When I run this, I get:

```
$ python a.py
German
```

Showing that the fish-owner is German. I think your original problem had a different but similar set of constraints, you can easily use the same strategy to solve your original.

It's also instructional to look at the output of:

```
print(m)
```

in the `sat` case. This prints:

```
[v5 = 4,
 v9 = 1,
 v16 = 2,
 v12 = 5,
 v14 = 1,
 v2 = 2,
 v0 = 3,
 v10 = 2,
 v18 = 4,
 v15 = 2,
 v6 = 3,
 v7 = 1,
 v4 = 5,
 v8 = 2,
 v17 = 1,
 v11 = 1,
 v1 = 5,
 v13 = 4,
 fishOwner = German,
 v3 = 4,
 nationality = [5 -> Swede,
                2 -> Dane,
                1 -> Norwegian,
                4 -> German,
                else -> Briton],
 color = [5 -> White,
          4 -> Green,
          1 -> Yellow,
          2 -> Blue,
          else -> Red],
 pet = [3 -> Bird,
        1 -> Cat,
        2 -> Horse,
        4 -> Fish,
        else -> Dog],
 beverage = [4 -> Coffee,
             3 -> Milk,
             5 -> Beer,
             1 -> Water,
             else -> Tea],
 sport = [1 -> Baseball,
          2 -> Volleyball,
          5 -> Tennis,
          4 -> Hockey,
          else -> Football]]
```

Ignore all the assignments to `vN` variables, those are the ones we used internally for modeling purposes. But you can see how z3 mapped each of the uninterpreted functions to the corresponding values. For all of these, the value mapped is the number of the house to the corresponding value that satisfies the puzzle constraints. You can programmatically extract a full solution to the puzzle as needed by using the information contained in this model.

Comment: I see Haskell for the first time and really doubt I can translate. But thanks for the insight.

Comment: Would you be so kind to drop a short Python version example? It doesn't have to include all constraints. Just to showcase the strategy.

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome, will study this example up down!

Comment: I can not understand which part ensures that "No owners have the same pet, smoke the same brand of cigar or drink the same beverage" and "There are 5 houses in five different colors". The code is some-have designed so, I don't need to add these conditions? If so, how could I brake the uniqueness if I need?

Comment: I added this `S.add(Distinct([c(i+1) for i in range(5)]))
S.add(Distinct([n(i+1) for i in range(5)]))
S.add(Distinct([b(i+1) for i in range(5)]))
S.add(Distinct([p(i+1) for i in range(5)]))
S.add(Distinct([s(i+1) for i in range(5)]))`

Comment: Sure, you can add those `Distinct` clauses. In this particular case, you do not need them since all the other constraints uniquely determine the output. You can experiment by removing a bunch of them and z3 will indeed find solutions where multiple people might have the same pet etc. In that case the distict constraints would be handy. As is typical in these sorts of puzzles, the constraints are given such that there's a unique solution, so no explicit distinct requirement is usually needed.